# Crystal-Lang C-Binding struct doesn't seem to pass null value

Tags: binding, crystal-lang

I'm currently trying to add c14n support for crystal-lang using a c-binding with [libxml2](http://www.xmlsoft.org/html/libxml-c14n.html).  I've successfully been able to use xmlC14NDocSave to save the canonical xml to a file.  The problem I'm having is with the xmlOutputBufferPtr for both xmlC14NDocSaveTo and xmlC14NExecute.

The error I receive is (Mac and Linux)

> xmlC14NExecute: output buffer encoder != NULL but C14N requires UTF8 output

The documentation states

> this buffer MUST have encoder==NULL because C14N requires UTF-8 output

in `src/C14N/lib_C14N.cr` I have the following code

```
type CharEncodingHandler = Void*
type Buff = Void*
#type OutputBuffer = Void*
struct OutputBuffer
  context : Void*
  writecallback : OutputWriteCallback
  closecallback : OutputCloseCallback
  encoder : CharEncodingHandler
  buffer  : Buff
  conv    : Buff
  written : Int32
  error   : Int32
end
....
fun xmlC14NDocSaveTo(doc : LibXML::Node*, nodes : LibXML::NodeSet*, mode : Mode, inclusive_ns_prefixes : UInt8**, with_comments : Int32, buf : OutputBuffer*) : Int32
fun xmlC14NExecute(doc : LibXML::Node*, is_visible_callback : IsVisibleCallback, user_data : Void*, mode : Mode, inclusive_ns_prefixes : UInt8**, with_comments : Int32, buf : OutputBuffer*) : Int32
```

In `src/C14N.cr`

```
output = XML::LibC14N::OutputBuffer.new
p output.encoder
XML::LibC14N.xmlC14NDocSaveTo(@xml, nil, @mode, nil, 0, out output)
```

The results of the p ouput.encoder are `Pointer(Void).null` so It appears the value is null.

The `c14n.c` function is just checking null on the buf->encoder struct

```
if (buf->encoder != NULL) {
    xmlGenericError(xmlGenericErrorContext,
                    "xmlC14NExecute: output buffer encoder != NULL but C14N requires UTF8 output\n");
    return (-1);
}
```

Any help would be appreciated, the code can be found on my [github](https://github.com/vonKingsley/C14N) account.  clone and run `crystal spec`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't specify `out output`, that simply reserves a block of memory of the size of the struct on the stack and passes a pointer to it. As of Crystal 0.7.6 it's not zeroed it out, so you pass garbage.

Using `output = XML::LibC14N::OutputBuffer.new` is already the first right step, since that does zero out the memory. Now to pass it, simply replace `out output` with `pointerof(output)`.

Comment: Thank you that helped.  For some reason after reading the documentation I thought out was just a shortcut for pointerof.